# How do I define my own type converters in Go?

Tags: go

I'm defining a type. I notice that Go has a type called `uint8` and a function called `uint8` which creates a `uint8` value.

But when I try to do this for myself:

```
12:    type myType uint32

14:    func myType(buffer []byte) (result myType) { ... }
```

I get the error

```
./thing.go:14: myType redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./thing.go:12
```

If I change it to `func newMyType` that works but it feels like I'm a second class citizen. Can I write type constructor functions with the same ident as type type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uint8()` isn't a function nor a constructor, but a [type conversion](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions).

For a primitive type (or other obvious conversions but I don't know the exact law), you don't need to create a constructor.

You can simply do this :

```
type myType uint32
v := myType(33)
```

If you have operations to do when creating your value, you should use a "make" function :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myType uint32

func makeMyType(buffer []byte) (result myType) {
    result = myType(buffer[0]+buffer[1])
    return
}

func main() {
    b := []byte{7, 8, 1}
    c := makeMyType(b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    fmt.Println("type of b :", reflect.TypeOf(b))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    fmt.Println("type of c :", reflect.TypeOf(c))
}
```

Naming a function `newMyType` should only be used when returning a pointer.

Comment: The conversion requires some bit-twiddling, I suppose it's it's more of a constructor than a C-style cast. Perhaps a type conversion isn't what I want.

Comment: BTW my example did state that it takes a `[]byte`.

Comment: The decision to create a constructor function or to use type conversion depends on the context.  For example, time.Duration simply uses conversion because it is a number, while time.Time has a construction function (time.Date) because it needs logic.